# A book maybe called Prison Planet, thought author was Alex Jones ? Not sure

Tags: story-identification

To my knowledge Alex Jones wrote a book titled Prison Planet. About: earth was where they (inner/inter/intra galactic powers that be) would send un-ruly, etc people. Earth was the prison planet for the bad folks.

Anyone know about this?

Thanks!

Comment: To my knowledge, Prison Planet is the name of Alex Jones’s [website.](http://www.prisonplanet.com/) He’s a radio host and occasional conspiracy theorist. Don’t know if he wrote a sci-fi book.

Comment: Here’s a list of all the SF works named [*Prison Planet*](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/se.cgi?arg=prison+planet&type=Fiction+Titles). None of the novels *seems* to match your description (and none is by Alex Jones) but a closer look might reveal something.

Comment: Alex Jones' work is more fantasy than sci-fi. I'm not sure he realizes it though.

Comment: Can you tell us where you first heard about this? Is it possible that you might be mistaking the name of Alex Jones’s website for a sci-fi novel?

Answer (score 1):

Prison Planet by Alex Jones is about the world becoming a one world government police state and the elites that have masterminded this plan.There is a film with the same title and content which is available on YouTube for free.

Comment: Is this a book, though? Also, is it science fiction? If this *is* the book, and it’s not science fiction (and merely Alex Jones’s theories about how the world is *actually* run), this question may not be on-topic.

Comment: @Adamant this is definitely a book and documentary by Alex Jones and it is about his theories on how the world is run. http://www.prisonplanet.com

Comment: Mr. Durden,  I can't seem to find that book on his website anywhere. Were you able to find it?

Comment: It was one of his first books from some time in the late 90's and I think its out of print. He primarily makes documentaries now and they are all on you tube. I think you can get a e book of prison planet on Amazon though.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Alex Jones used to appear on the Coast to Coast AM radio show with Art Bell talking about how Earth was an intergalactic prison. I don't remember a book, but it wouldn't surprise me.

Earth as a prison is where he got the website title PrisonPlanet.com. It seems as if he has been able to wipe his UFO conspiracies off the interwebs which I am not sure how that is possible.

Comment: The OP is looking for the book so I’m not sure if this properly answers the question. However, it does contain useful information about Alex Jones and the prison planet in other media’s which could be what the OP is looking for and they are mistaken so it is somewhat useful.

Answer (score -3):

The story you mention seems similar to the plot (if you can call it that) for highlander 2

The second "Highlander" movie, again with Christopher Lambert and Sean Connery. It's the year 2024 and all the ozone above Earth has gone. To protect people from dying, MacLeod helped in the construction of a giant "shield", several years ago. But, since there isn't left anyone Immortal after MacLeod's victory in the previous film, he has stopped being an Immortal himself. Now he is just an old man, until one day some other Immortals arrive on our planet. You see, the Immortals come from another planet...

Katana orders his men to capture Ramirez and MacLeod alive and kill the rest of the rebels. The two captives are put on trial by Zeist's priests, who sentence them to be exiled and reborn on Earth in pursuit of "The Prize." Winning the Prize gives the victor the choice to either grow old and die on Earth, or to return to Zeist.